# RC522 RFID card suddnely stopped working on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, rfid, mfrc522

i have RC522 RFID module and recently stopped reading on raspberry pi
i enter the write code but nothing happen (tried on diffrent chips )
i have already worked with it few days before and it was working just fine
since i thought it damaged i tried it on Arduino uno and it worked fine
i even checked and enbaled SPI again but nothing is working
i hope someone can help me i'm doing my final project and i'm running out of time

(i checkec pins many times and they're correct i used this tutorial with wiring and code : https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/)

the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = input('New data:')
        print("Now place your tag to write")
        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

i managed to make this work
following exactly what i did

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
sudo pip3 install spidev
sudo pip3 install mfrc522

mkdir ~/pi-rfid 
cd ~/pi-rfid
sudo nano Write.py
```

and the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = input('New data:')
        print("Now place your tag to write")
        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

and if it didnt work i recommend

```
mkdir ~/pi-rfid  #u don’t have to do this if u already made this
cd ~/pi-rfid
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
sudo pip3 install spidev
sudo pip3 install mfrc522
#baiscly we installing it inside the folder itself
```

and write the code above then run by

```
sudo python3 Write.py
```

Comment: I have the same problem. None of the fixes are working

Comment: i fixed the problem!!!

Comment: That's it? I don't see the difference to what you did previously.

Comment: If you fixed the problem, why not post an answer?